# Hitting ENTER on quickfix error jumps to an empty buffer

Tags: vim

I'm using GVim 8.1 on Windows 10 with no external plugins.
I have the following set up in my .gvimrc file:

```
let g:build_file_abs_path = fnamemodify(findfile("windows-build.bat", ";."), ":p:h")

" This build script is a basic wrapper for 'clang.exe file.c -o file.exe' style invocation
let &makeprg=g:build_file_abs_path . "\\windows-build.bat"

nnoremap <silent> <C-B> :cd <C-R>=g:build_file_abs_path<CR> <bar> make! <bar> copen <bar> redraw <bar> cd -<CR>
```

Now, this automatically opens a quickfix window with the correct compiler output. However, when I press ENTER over the error, the cursor jumps to the buffer for the affected file, yet it is completely blank with a single line. Furthermore, this occurs as I use `:cn` and `:cp` commands inside the quickfix window. e.g:

Images showing these two states:
[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s06JV.png)
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/as0Wr.png)

Please note that:
`:verbose nmap <CR>` returns no mappings, so there is not conflict there.

I would appreciate it if someone could provide some insight as to how to avoid the buffer becoming empty and actually jump to the error in the appropriate file. Many thanks.

Comment: most likely, the build script is run from a different path and while the output can be parsed into a quickfix buffer, Vim will try to open the file from a different path. Check the output of `:pwd` and the path from where your build script is running. Might make sense to add a `:cd foobar; ` into your `makeprg` option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Christian Brabandt's comment, I was able to solve the issue. I was misunderstanding the distinction between the working directories of vim and the build script. I made the following changes:

```
let &makeprg="cd " . g:build_file_abs_path . " && windows-build.bat"
nnoremap <silent> <C-B> :make! <bar> copen <bar> redraw <CR>
```